# Handler Timer is not working

Tags: android, timer

I tried to create a small timer for my programm but this code below is not working and i cant find the issue

```
private int mInterval = 5000; 
private Handler mHandler;

// at the bottom of my onCreate() methode:

    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
}
// on create ends here

 Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
     @Override 
     public void run() {
         myview.loadUrl(readFromFile());
         mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
     }
 };

 void startRepeatingTask() {
     mStatusChecker.run(); 
 }
```

I really would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler.post()` or `Handler.postDelayed()` to start a Handler.

```
private int mInterval = 5000; 
private Handler mHandler;

// at the bottom of my onCreate() methode:

mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(mStatusChecker);
//mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);//or use this method
//startRepeatingTask();
// on create ends here

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        myview.loadUrl(readFromFile());
      mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
    }
};

//void startRepeatingTask() {
//    mStatusChecker.run(); 
//}
```

You may need to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for read file in storage, and `android.permission.INTERNET` for load url.

Comment: can you post some crash log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rBtryXQs with the postDelayed() , it works for 5 seconds and when the handler is called it crashes

Comment: it's fileNotFound exception, the code can't find the file, pls make sure `url.txt` is in the dir, also, try to check the permission, i find `Permission denied`.

Comment: this happens because im logging this from my desktop. On my smartphone the readFromFile() function works fine

Comment: This exception appears if you use custom ROM, like cyanogenmod. You can try to add `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />`, if it doesn't work, there is no way to prevent it.[http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/no-eglconfig-found-t6129.html](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/no-eglconfig-found-t6129.html)

Comment: I think it is the webview related code lead to the crash, not the handler. Try to replace `myview.loadUrl(readFromFile());` with `Log.i()` or `System.out.println()` to see if the handler work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :)

```
//set variables
private int mInterval = 5000; 
private Handler handler = new Handler();
//start runnable
runme.run();

private Runnable runme = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
         //repeat after 5000 milliseconds
         handler.postDelayed(this, mInterval );
    }
};

//stop runnable
handler.removeCallbacks(runme);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do something here... 
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // for interval...
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private int mInterval = 5000; 
private Handler mHandler;

// at the bottom of my onCreate() methode:

mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker,mInterval);
}
// on create ends here

 Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
     @Override 
 public void run() {
     myview.loadUrl(readFromFile());
      //if you want to repeat the thread infinitely,then add below code also. Else remove it
     mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
 }
 };
```